# firewall config for gen<i>cam / GigE vision camera discovery and communication

Tags: udp, port, network-protocols, genicam

I need to configure an otherwise closed firewall (to LAN) to allow gencam / GigE Vision camera discovery and communication.

The standard itself is unfortunately not publicly available, but the communication seems to be happening at UDP/3956 (information based on [this page](http://www.roborealm.com/help/GenICam.php) and [this page](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/5651/en/)) but I am not sure if I need more than just opening open UDP/3956, whether this port is used also for discovery (besides control/data transfer) and so on.

Anyone knowledgeable can answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GigEVision devices listen on the port 3956 of their ethernet interface, for all control packets, discovery packets included. They answer using acknowledge packets using the same port.

The video stream packets will be emited by another port of the devices.